# Saving Spark dataFrames as parquet files - no errors, but data is not being saved

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I want to save a dataframe as a parquet file in Python, but I am only able to save the schema, not the data itself.

I have reduced my problem down to a very simple Python test case, which I copied below from IPYNB.

Any advice on what might be going on?

```
In [2]:

import math
import string
import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot
from pyspark.sql import *
import pylab
import random
import time

In [3]:

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
​#create a simple 1 column dataframe a single row of data
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(xrange(1)).flatMap(lambda x[Row(col1="Test row")]))
df.show()
df.count()

Out[3]:
col1    
Test row

1L

In [4]:
# Persist the dataframe as a parquet file
df.saveAsParquetFile("test.parquet")

In [5]: 
ls

TrapezoidRule.ipynb         metastore_db/
WeatherPrecipitation.ipynb  derby.log                  test.parquet/

In [6]: 
ls -l test.parquet
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users   0 Oct  4 14:13 _SUCCESS
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users 188 Oct  4 14:13 _common_metadata

In [7]: 
# The directory listing shows that the test parquet was created, but there are no data files.
# load the parquet file into another df and show that no data was saved or loaded... only the schema
newDF = sqlContext.parquetFile("test.parquet")
newDF.show()
newDF.count()

Out[7]: 
col1

0L
```

Comment: did you solve your problem?
Which spark version are you using?

Comment: I'm having this same issue with Spark2.2 running in local mode.  Did you ever figure out what was wrong?

Comment: I will put a simple example using databricks below ...

Answer (score 0):

For azure databricks and synapse I have used this to write or create parquet file.

The parquet files create multiple files when saving including metadata. If your dataset is large it will create multiple parquet files. That's why specifying name to parquet files generates this kind of error.
Always use path only. It will create files inside folder.
You should use "test" only, your parquet files will be created inside test.

To access you can use "test/*.parquet"

```
 df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(s"parquet file path")
```