# Spark DataFrameWriter saves parquet file without any data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet

I think that I must be missing something obvious here, but I am having trouble writing and reading Spark2.2 `DataFrames` to parquet files.  I'm trying to do some simple data processing where I load a csv file, nuke out a couple column values, and then save the result.  However, spark keeps writing empty parquet files instead of the my data.

```scala
/* SparkApp running in loca[*] mode */
val data = spark.read
    .option("header", "false")
    .option("inferSchema", false)
    .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
    .option("delimiter", "|")
    .schema(My.schema)
    .csv("/path/to/my/data.csv")

data.count
//res: Long=100000

val parquetPath = "/path/to/data.parquet"
data.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(parquetPath)

val newData = spark.read.parquet(parquetPath)
/* newData will have the same (correct) schema as data, but: */

newData.count
//res: Long=0
```

I can see from the resulting file sizes that the parquet file is not saving down the accompanying data, so I presume that I am doing something wrong with `DataFrameWriter`, but I'm not sure what.  Do I have to collect or materialize the data before writing or something?

**Update**

Looks to be a similar issue to this [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32938349/saving-spark-dataframes-as-parquet-files-no-errors-but-data-is-not-being-save).

Comment: What does `data.show` give you?

Comment: An empty dataframe.  Has all the correct columns but no rows.  And `data.schema` is equal to `newData.schema`, but the actual data is missing.

Comment: it seems there is some problem in local mode, seen in one of comments

Comment: @Achyuth Comment on JIRA or somewhere?